# how to close hibernate tools db connections

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, hibernate-tools

When developing a new project I often want to re-create the schema to apply any new entities or relationships created. I like using hibernate tools in eclipse, but it's a pain when wanting drop and re-create the schema - since it seems to maintain open connections to the db (postgres in this case).

Does anybody know if there is an easy way of getting the eclipse hibernate tools plugin to close off all connections?

Answer (score 1):

It might be helpful to tell you, that i was using Hibernate Tools for creating the schema, too. I never had the problem you are describing. Nowadays i use [liquibase](http://liquibase.org) for schema migration. It is a different approach, but i like it.

Answer (score 0):

I'v never hit this problem before, but we use Maven run from the command line to create/update the schema and also DBUnit to upload data.  Then back to elcipse...